# Automatically Update React Component Based on External Class Property Changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an external JavaScript class (MyClass) with a property (number) that changes automatically, but I need to update a React component whenever this property changes.  I cannot modify the external class (MyClass), only the react component.

**Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(name, number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    setInterval(() => this.incrementNumber(), 1000);
  }

  incrementNumber() {
    this.number += 1;
  }
}
```

**And the React component:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState(new MyClass("omri", 0));

  useEffect(() => {
    // How can I automatically update the component when obj.number changes?
  }, [obj]);

  return (
    <div>
      {obj.name} {obj.number}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Constraints:**
Cannot modify the MyClass external class.
Need to update the React component automatically when the number property in the external class (MyClass) changes.

*What are the alternative approaches or solutions to automatically update the React component when the number property in the external class changes without altering the class?*

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding an updated answer that doesn't change anything in the class. You need to use `useSyncExternalStore` and [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useSyncExternalStore } from "react";

let subscriptions = [];

class MyClass {
  constructor(name, number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    setInterval(() => {
      obj.incrementNumber();
    }, 1000);
  }

  incrementNumber() {
    this.number += 1;
  }
}

const obj = new Proxy(new MyClass("omri", 0), {
  set(target, property, value) {
    target[property] = value;
    subscriptions.forEach((p) => p(value));
    return true;
  }
});

const subscribe = (listener) => {
  subscriptions.push(listener);
  return () => (subscriptions = subscriptions.filter((l) => l !== listener));
};

const getSnapshot = () => {
  return `${obj.name}:${obj.number}`;
};

export default function App() {
  const store = useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapshot);
  let [name, number] = store.split(":");

  return (
    <div>
      {name} {number}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Changes:

1. `subscriptions` to keep track of the listeners. I chose to make this an array if you want to use the same `MyClass` object in multiple components.
2. Made a `Proxy` over the `MyClass` object. The handler for this `Proxy` has a trap on set that updates the value and fires all the `subscriptions`.
3. `subscribe` and `getSnapshot` functions. Note that the `getSnapshot` function should return the same value every time. I chose to make it a string, you can go with another solution if your class is complicated.

Demo on code sandbox: [image: Edit priceless-booth-x5r98p]

While I do feel like this is a bit overkill, this is the only solution that came to my mind. I'll update the answer if I find anything simpler.

#### Old Answer that edits the class

You can use `useSyncExternalStore` to sync React with external stores. Something like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useSyncExternalStore } from "react";

let subscription = undefined;

class MyClass {
  constructor(name, number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
  }

  incrementNumber() {
    this.number += 1;
    if (!!subscription) subscription();
  }
}

const obj = new MyClass("omri", 0);

const subscribe = (listener) => {
  subscription = listener;
  return () => (subscription = undefined);
};

const getSnapshot = () => {
  return `${obj.name}:${obj.number}`;
};

setInterval(() => obj.incrementNumber(), 1000);

export default function App() {
  const store = useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapshot);
  let name, number;
  if (store) [name, number] = store.split(":");

  return (
    <div>
      {name} {number}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The changes I made are:

1. `subscription` variable to keep track of the listeners.
2. call the `subscription` in `incrementNumber`
3. `subscribe` and `getSnapshot` functions. Note that the `getSnapshot` function should return the same value everytime. I chose to make it a string, you can go with another solution if your class is complicated.

More info can be found in the [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore#usage)

Comment: he doesnt want to modify the class, your approach modifies it

Comment: updated the anwer

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution! It seems like a clever approach to achieving reactivity for an external class without modifying it. I'm wondering if there might be a simpler way to achieve this, as this solution introduces some complexity. I appreciate your help and any further insights you can provide. Thank you again!

Comment: @OmriHalifa When you think about it, all complex parts are required. `useSyncExternalStore` is the hook intended to sync react with an external data source. The `Proxy` is necessary since you cannot modify the class.

Comment: I suppose the handler doesn't need to have a get trap. It's left over from debugging. I'll remove it

Comment: Is there an alternative approach that doesn't require changing the constructor of `MyClass` but still achieves the goal of updating the React component when the `number` property in the external class changes? Your insights are much appreciated!

Comment: ```class MyClass {
  constructor(name, number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    setInterval(() => {
      number+=1
    }, 1000);
  }

  incrementNumber() {
    this.number += 1;
  }
}``` This how i want myClass will be

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I missed that line. Will you be expecting to update the class variables from within the class? If so there is no way to do this without periodically firing the subscriptions.